# Problem with 'skiprows' when reading csv with pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a big dataframe (~5 millions rows) that has some wrong data in it.
I have identified the indexes of the rows with wrong data and now I am trying to remove the 'wrong' rows from the dataframe.

Due to the size of the dataframe, I am using the `chunksize` feature while reading the csv.
To skip the 'wrong' rows, I am using the `skiprows` and `error_bad_lines features`.
I also use the `low_memory` feature to prevent warnings (and for the purpose of the example I read only the first 20 000 rows).
Then I save the new dataframe in a new csv.

The problem is that that only the 9 first 'wrong' rows are skipped, then 'wrong rows' are still read (and saved to the output csv).

Here is my code:

```
for df in pd.read_csv('database.csv', chunksize=1000, nrows=20000,
                       low_memory=False, error_bad_lines=False, skiprows=wrong_id_list):
    df.to_csv('database_fixed.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

where `wrong_id_list`  is the list of indexes of the rows I want to remove:

`[2689, 3251, 3254, 3589, 3885, 8301, 10062, 10570, 10883, 13118, 16153, 16237, 17601, 18099, 18676]`

when checking `database_fixed.csv` I can see that the following rows have wrong data:

`[13108, 16142, 16225, 17588, 18085, 18661]` So I imagine rows are still being skipped but not the right ones.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're counting it 0 based? In any case, I don't think it's possible to reproduce your problem based on your description. Try it on a table of 5 rows, and try to skip some. If it doesn't work the way you think, post a question about it using something people can try on their own.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what means : "counting it 0 based"
Of course I've forgotten to say that I am a python-beginner.
But ok, I'll try that and come back with a smaller example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to remove bad rows is to do it explicitely

```
df = df.loc[~df.index.isin(list_of_bad_rows]),]
```

Comment: the console returns an error when I am trying this command. It dislikes the "!"

Comment: I think they meant ```~``` instead of ```!```

Comment: this is what happens when one works in R and Python... thanks dude

Comment: so it works perfectly (thanks!) and what is also great, is that it processes the file faster. It is not needed anymore to chunk the file.